# Is it possible to calculate odds ratio(95% CI) for only control group?

Tags: odds-ratio, case-control-study

The original data contains scores of case/control group. The score is the number of risk alleles multiplied by the regression coefficient for SNP. So in the data, case samples have higher score than control samples.
[image]

```
 ID   disease     Score  
001      case      5.93
002      case      6.12  
003      case      6.54
004   control      3.67
005   control      2.33
006   control      1.24
```

Now I grouping control samples in decile, and I want to calculate odds ratio for each decile. Finally output a plot like below.  Can anyone please tell me how can I calculate this in R or other software?

[image]

Comment: If I understood correctly your question, the answer should be $1$ because the OR of a group $j$ is defined as $OR_j = \frac{odds(group_j)}{odds(control)}$.